# webmethod: cannot implicity convert type string to int

Tags: c#, web-services, soap

Hi with this code I get: cannot implicity convert type string to int.

```
        CalculateSumOfList.ServiceReference1.Service1SoapClient client = new CalculateSumOfList.ServiceReference1.Service1SoapClient();
        CalculateSumOfList.ServiceReference1.ArrayOfInt arrayOfInt = new CalculateSumOfList.ServiceReference1.ArrayOfInt();
        arrayOfInt.AddRange(listInt);
        int result = client.CalculateSum(arrayOfInt); //error here!
        label1.Text = Convert.ToString(result);
```

The webmethod I am calling is here:

```
namespace CalculateWebServiceSum
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for Service1
    /// </summary>
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
    // [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class Service1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {

        [WebMethod]
        public string CalculateSum(List<int> listInt)
        {
            int[] sum = listInt.ToArray();

            return sum.ToString();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you keep asking the same question? Was there something wrong with the question you asked an hour ago?

Comment: sorry the other question was related to my initial problem of int to string this is related to calling the sum function of a webservice.

Comment: But it's exactly the same problem!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message is pretty clear. Your method, `CalculateSum()` returns a string. On the line  that the error occurs, you're attempting to use the string result to set the value of an int:

```
int result = client.CalculateSum(arrayOfInt);
^ type int   ^ returns string
```

**Option 1**

I suggest changing your `CalculateSum()` to this:

```
public int CalculateSum(List<int> listInt)
{
    return listInt.Sum();
}
```

**Note:** I'm not sure why you're passing a `List<int>` to a web service to be summed. If you have `List<int>`, simply call `List<int>.Sum()`, no WS needed.

**Option 2**

Since you're calling `.ToString()` on the int after retrieving it, why not just retrieve it as a string?

```
string result = client.CalculateSum(arrayOfInt);

public string CalculateSum(List<int> listInt)
{
    return listInt.Sum().ToString();
}
```

Comment: how can i work around it? All im trying to do is calculate the sum of a list but call it from a webservice?

Comment: Why do you want the web-service to do something trivial that you can do on the client side? That's like calling your web-service to make a string uppercase.

Comment: @Øyvind Knobloch-Bråthen, I don't want the WS to do something trivial, the OP does. Take a look at my note under **Option 1**. I said the same thing to the OP.

Comment: @JamesHill - My comment was aimed at Garrith's comment to your answer, and not to your answer. Should have pointed that out :)

Answer (score 2):

`CalculateSum` returns a string

```
public string CalculateSum(List<int> listInt)
```

and you are assigning it to an integer variable.

```
int result = ...
```

I would change `CalculateSum` to return an integer.

Answer (score 2):

You have lots of problems here. First, your `CalculateSum` method returns a string, but you try to store that into an int.

```
int result = client.CalculateSum(arrayOfInt);
```

So first thing you need to so is to change CalculateSum to return an int instead. At that point you will see that CalculateSum returns ..... `System.Int32[]`. Also, the basic ToString  for a intArray. So your logic is quite flawed as well. Let's fix that up.

```
public int CalculateSum(List<int> listInt)
{
  int sum = listInt.Sum();
  return sum.ToString();
}
```

Then you will probably find out that you don't need the method at all, and can just do it like this

```
int result = arrayOfInt.Sum();
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
int result = client.CalculateSum(arrayOfInt); //error here!
```

To

```
string result = client.CalculateSum(arrayOfInt); // no errors here!
```

But it is better to change the signature of your method to return an int, because sum is a number.

```
[WebMethod]
public int CalculateSum(List<int> listInt)
{
    return listInt.Sum();    
}
```

Comment: He's got the web service source code, so let's assume that he can change it, in which case it would be best to change the web service.

Comment: @ShellShock yeah I figured it out and already updated the answer.

Comment: In this case `result` will be System.Int32[]`. Hardly useful for the OP (even if it compiles without error)

Comment: @Øyvind Knobloch-Bråthen could you please explain your doubts? Why it will not compile? The method signature in the OP question returns string, but his usage implies that he wants to sum elements, LINQ Sum returns an int.

Comment: @oleksii - I wrote my comment before I reloaded and saw your edit+comment. OP's Calculatesum method returns the default `ToString` for the array itself (`System.Int32[]`), and since our first answer was just changing int result to string result, that would set result to `System.Int32[]`. Your current answer should work just fine :)

Answer (score 0):

The CalculateSum web method does not do what its name suggests - it does not return the sum of the list of integers, but rather the type name, i.e., "System.Int32[]". Assuming you really want the sum of the integers, and you can change the web method, then I suggest the following:

```
    [WebMethod]
    public int CalculateSum(List<int> listInt)
    {
         return listInt.Sum();
    }
```

You don't need to change the caller.